# VBScript LDAP Query Does not pull back all results

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to run an LDAP Query in VBScript against AD. If i do not set the property "Page Size" It will return results but not all. I get a record count of 960. However, when i set the page size to any number It appears to get all the records because now my count is +5400. The problem is all the records are blank.

```
Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection

' Search entire Active Directory domain.
Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")

strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
strBase = "LDAP://" & strDNSDomain

strQuery = "Select " & strAttributes & " FROM '" & strBase & "' Where objectCategory = 'computer' OR objectCategory = 'user'"
adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
adoCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = 2
adoCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False 
adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 100 'Note if this is set to any number all results are blank
adoCommand.Properties("Size Limit") = 75000
adoCommand.Properties("Time Out") = 300

' Run the query.
Wscript.Echo "Running Query"
Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute
Wscript.Echo "Finished Query"
Wscript.Echo adoRecordset.RecordCount 
'If "Page Size" is set to any number this will be +5400 but all records will be blank. If i don't set page size i get 960, the records aren't blank but i am not getting the 5400 total records

For i = 1 To adoRecordset.RecordCount
    name = adoRecordset.Fields("name").Value
    description = adoRecordset.Fields("description").Value
    displayName = adoRecordset.Fields("displayName").Value
    createOutputLine(Array(name,descritpion,displayName))'This just takes the result and writes it to a file
    adoRecordset.MoveNext
Next

adoRecordset.Close
adoConnection.Close
```

Any ideas on why i am not getting all records? Or why if i set the page size the values are empty?

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out how to work with LDAP in classic ASP. I need to [convert my PHP code into classic ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008321/how-do-i-transform-my-php-ldap-connection-bind-and-search-into-a-vbscript-code). [**Getting Started With ASP and ADSI**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705944(v=vs.85).aspx)